# GetTraceSummaries response doesn't include "ServiceIds"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I'm trying to use `XRay#GetTraceSummaries` in order to gather statistics on all of my companies services. However [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/api/API_GetTraceSummaries.html) says that the response object should include allot more things than what I'm actually getting. Most notably I'm missing the `ServiceIds` field. Do i need to set something up in the instrumentation of the services in order for this to be included?

Answer (score 0):

The API `GetTraceSummaries` can help you quickly discover trace ids that satisfy a certain criteria https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-filters.html#console-filters-syntax. The returned results only carry minimum information at trace level for performance. You can then use the discovered trace ids to retrieve the full trace data by calling `BatchGetTraces`.

What specific information you are looking for on service level in a trace summary context? Did you check `GetServiceGraph` which returns all services with statistics (fault/error/throttle count)?

Answer (score 0):

Postman call for AWS Xray API GetTraceSummaries.

1. Go to Postman.
2. Choose the request type as POST.
3. The URL to post the call is https://xray.region.amazonaws.com/Traces, i.e., https://xray.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Traces.
4. Go to Authorization Tab.

   - Choose Type → AWS Signature → Provide AWS Access key and Secret key.
   - Choose Request Headers → Advanced and set the region and Service name.
     AWS region to your region, Service name to xray.
   - Example:

     - AWS region → us-east-1
     - Service name → xray
5. Go to Headers Tab. Set the following Headers:

   - X-Amz-Target → XRay.GetTraceSummaries
   - Content-Type → application/json
6. Go to Body → Choose raw and Add the following in the body: `"TraceIds":[traceid1]`

   ```json
   {
       "TraceIds": [ "1-655122ff-9af64687442353194ff4da94" ]
   }
   ```

**Note:**

1. `TraceIds` string used in the request body is case-sensitive and make sure to use the same string.
2. Extend the body with `StartTime` and `EndTime` for more customized response. Refer AWS documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/api/API_Operations.html